# How to save my xml file as PDF file using C#

Tags: c#, xml, pdf, silverlight-4.0

i am converting silver light grid view into XML. it opening in excel exactly.
what i need is while saving the file as xml.i need to convert that my file into pdf formate.

either i have to use Save As PDF option through coding. are i have convert my data into pdf formate.

suggest me to this task perfectly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you need one of the pdf converting tools

http://bytes.com/topic/net/answers/177492-xml-pdf-using-c-asp-net